# Is there a way to automatically make CSS/HTML changes to a web page each time it is loaded?

Tags: firebug, browser-automation

I sometimes use Firebug to fix problems with webpages or to hide certain things. I am simply a user of these webpages and cannot change the source. I would like to be able to automate this so that each time I visit a website, certain modifications are performed. Right now, I need to redo the same edits each time the page is loaded.

I am open to using other tools than Firebug, since I'm not sure it is capable of doing this.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Greasemonkey is good if you need to make HTML changes, but if it's just appearance and/or CSS changes, use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).  Stylish is easier to code, runs faster and cleans the page as it is loaded (GM has to wait until everything but some images is loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used Greasemonkey for this task.